# How can I strip a single quote from a dataTable.Select( ) query in C#?

Tags: c#, datatable.select

So I have a list of dealers names and I am searching them in my datatable -- problem is, some chucklehead HAS to be named 'Young's' --- this causes an error.

```
drs = dtDealers.Select("DealerName = '" + dealerName + "'");
```

So I tried to replace the string (although it didnt work for me - maybe I dont know how to use replace...)

```
 DataRow[] drs;
                if (dealerName.Contains("'"))
                {
                    string dealerSearch = dealerName;
                    dealerSearch = dealerSearch.Replace("'", "\'");
                    drs = dtDealers.Select("DealerName = '" + dealerSearch + "'");
                }
                else
                {
                    drs = dtDealers.Select("DealerName = '" + dealerName + "'");
                }
```

Anyone have any good ideas?

Thanks!
Todd

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the @ operator called the verbatim operator which means literal in latin. It will not do any interpretation of the characters within the string that would otherwise mean something.

Answer (score 10):

i usually use double single quote to denote one i.e.

```
DealerName = 'Young''s'
```

Try that

Comment: This is what worked for me. 

drs = dtDealers.Select("DealerName = '" + dealerName.Replace(@"'", "''") + "'");

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Ultimately you might want to consider using a parameterized query. This will solve your problem and some others you may not have thought of yet. I found [this link](http://it.toolbox.com/wiki/index.php/How_do_I_escape_single_quotes_in_SQL_queries%3F) which details the reasons why and how.

Answer (score 2):

The double-single quote will fix the problem, but an extra note: Your "else" block is redundant.

You could accomplish the same thing by doing this:

```
 DataRow[] drs;
                if (dealerName.Contains("'"))
                {
                    string dealerSearch = dealerName;
                    dealerSearch = dealerSearch.Replace("'", "''");
                }
                drs = dtDealers.Select("DealerName = '" + dealerName + "'");
```

Comment: I dont think it was .. I was searching with the dealerSearch if I had a single quote but searching with the dealerName if I did not... I did not want to changed the 'dealerName' variable because I use it later on ...

Comment: You don't need to change dealerName, and the if block in this answer is redundant, too.  You can *always* use dealerSearch for the criteria because if the name does not contain the single-quote character, the replace function will just return the unmodified string. That will make your code simpler. See the answer from CharithJ

Answer (score 1):

```
drs = dtDealers.Select("DealerName = '" + dealerName.Replace("'", "\\'") + "'");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the `\`: `dealerSearch.Replace("'", "\\'")`  (or use an `@` literal)

Your `\` is treated as a C# escape and doesn't appear in the actual string.