# DataTable.Select with ' (single quote) Character in the query vb.net

Tags: vb.net, select, datatable, escaping

I have a string like `"Hello'World"` and a DataTable with some records in it. One of those records is `"Hello'World".`

The problem is, when I do a .Select in the DataTable, it only tries to search for the "Hello" part and throws an error on "World" because it interprets the ' (single quote) like the closing quote on sql.

```
DataTable.Select("text = 'Hello'World'")
```

I have gone through msdn doc, and it says I can escape some characters with [] brackets or f.slashes \, but I just can't figure out: `.select("text = 'Hello[']world'")`

I've done some reading: [Verbatim in vb - c#](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=522918) and "jmcilhinney" explains it really well. BUT, it did not answer my question for what I want to do. In stackoverflow.com, [a same question is posted but in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6221770/how-can-i-strip-a-single-quote-from-a-datatable-select-query-in-c), but I can't find a way to use @ in vb.

Can you please redirect me to more doc, examples or any one of you have ever encountered this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Use ''  (this is 2 ' characters).

```
DataTable.select("text = 'Hello''World'")
```

Comment: But it do not select all rows in my problem! That is;<br>
    DataTable.Select("city = 'O'Fallon'","");

Comment: Try DataTable.Select("city='O''Fallon'","");

Comment: There should be a checkmark next to my answer that you need to click on to "Accept" the answer.  It looks like you voted my answer Up (for which I'm grateful), but haven't actually marked my answer as accepted yet.